# Why do files get corrupt on hard reboot?

Tags: hard-drive

When you save a text file, change the content, save again and press the hardware reboot button the file has a high chance of becoming corrupt(!) (all content turned to \0 characters). I can reproduce this on different machines using Windows 7, 8.1 and 10, even if I wait several seconds, close the file or even close the application. I tried it with Notepad, Notepad++, Paint, file copy in explorer and a naive UWP file read/write application. I was baffled when I first saw this behavior and don't understand why in 2017 you still can't rely on your files being save after a sudden power-loss.

- Should you expect files to become corrupt like that on a sudden power-loss?
- When and how do you know if a file is persisted "for real" on a hard-disk drive?
- Why do files still get corrupt like that and which safety nets should prevent this?
- If there are safety nets involved under which circumstances can they fail?

I imagine that files are not actually written to their designated place when using a file_write() operation because there is a some caching and journaling involved and in the end the operating system and/or disk controller decide when this is done. But I thought that journaling in particular was invented to prevent this. And the actual file write should happen when calling a file_flush() or file_close() operation.

Update: There is an option in Windows -> Device Manager -> Disk drives -> MyDiskDrive -> Properties -> Policies -> [x] Enable write caching on the device

> Improves system performance by enabling write caching on the device,
>   but a power outage or equipment failure might result in data loss
>   or corruption

This matches exactly the behavior described above, except even if I disable write-caching, make a clean reboot and test again, the files still become corrupt. WTF?

Comment: NTFS does not have data journaling, only metadata journaling.

Comment: Huh, you are right.
"NTFS is a journaling file system ... to record *metadata changes* to the volume. ... The USN Journal ... can be enabled or disabled on non-system volumes."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Journaling
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363877%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft engineer Raymond Chen has written two article on the check box you are asking about:

- [Flushing your performance down the drain, that is](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100909-00/?p=12913/)
- [Dangerous setting is dangerous: This is why you shouldn’t turn off write cache buffer flushing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130416-00/?p=4643/)

However, there are several layers of caching, some of them out of the operating system's control, so much so that without issuing a shutdown command, it is impossible to be certain that a given file is written.

If you are concerned about your data integrity, buy a UPS. That'll solve your power failure problem.

Comment: Thx. We get reports about "lost savegames" on Windows Phone devices and I can't tell our customers to buy UPS devices... for phones :)

Comment: @Gerold Meisinger Windows Phones have a battery. They don't need UPS. I don't think the reason there is power failure.

Comment: Battery empty or removed.

Comment: Yeah. Not enough warnings in the whole wide world for some people...